# Inter-device communication via Bluetooth using Phonegap on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm wondering if it's possible for a Phonegap-based app on one android device to communicate with another Phonegap-based app on another device via Bluetooth?

If it's possible to do this kind of thing with some native Java code for Android, then it should be possible via Phonegap by wrapping that code up as a Phonegap plugin, right...?

From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) on Bluetooth, I understand one device needs to act as a server and listen for incoming connections and the other "client" needs to initiate by connecting to the server. This would work in the scenario I'm envisaging with two slightly different apps, a "master" app running on a tablet which controls a "slave" app running on a phone, for example.

[This BluetoothSerial plugin](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial) seems like it might be useful, as it provides functionality for both listening and for initiating a connection. Has anyone use this plugin for communication between android devices?

Comment: I have used a plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/Android/Bluetooth. I had to enhance it for reading and writing. It seems the plugin you provided has all those features and you should be able to work with it. You can definitely share data with Bluetooth in a Phonegap application

Answer (score -1):

Check the following two links hope it will answer your question:

1. https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/blob/e1f1b330747c7c656e567bbd51a568067337e756/README.md
2. https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial